# Is there a history of tag changes on git?

Tags: git

long story short, i had an automatic build issue where old git tags were force tagged to different revisions.

Every for the last days re-tagged a old version:

```
a6b60aa...c00ae32 v1.3.0 -> v1.3.0 (forced update)
```

Is there any way to restore this? are tag changes stored in any log? I only have the build logs for the last ones and am already looking for a working copy that haven't updated in the last days.

Comment: You could check the ref log?

Comment: That's nasty, because no, the repo does not store that information. Do you have backups from before that change was made, or someone's repo who did not fetch since the change was made?

Comment: Re: the ref log, I believe it would only show you old tag locations if you had checked out that tag before.